# Item templates disappeared in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

When one of use right clicks on a folder (within a solution) and chooses "Add Item" we get a dialog where we can pick what we want to create (e.g. a C# class, interface, text file....)

Well...
Currently I am missing all C# related things like classes, no text files, ...

What I can choose from:

```
Visual C# 
  General: Assembly Information File
  AspNetCore: editorconfig File (.NET)
              editorconfig File (default)
              Text Template
              Typescript File
              Typescript JSX File
              Javascript JSON Configuration File
              Typescript JSON Configuration File

              CSharp: Text Template
              General: editorconfig File (.NET)
                       editorconfig File (default)

              Web: TypeScript File
                   TypeScript JSX File
                   JavaScript JSON Configuration File
                   TypeScript JSON Configuration File
```

or group online

What happened to my "Add C# class" and so on?

Comment: Does it matter what type of project you try to add an item? Did you update your Visual Studio?

Comment: Seems to be gone for ASP.NET Core Web API. In .NET Core Console Application everything is fine. Thx for asking :-) Thought it would be gone for everything so far. Can't remember that I would have made an update in the last time, thougth I am on Community 16.10.2. So pretty fresh

Comment: Funny! If I create a second project in the same solution as the web API everything works as expected too. Just the project with the web API is messed up.